# Looking out from the inside of an Alcubierre bubble

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, warp-drives

Disregarding the difficulties in *achieving* a warp "bubble" as per Alcubierre's theoretical warp drive, as far as I understand it the geometry of the spacetime that arises is mathematically sound. Hence, it should be possible to predict what it would look like to be on the inside of the bubble looking out, right? Does there exist any resources on this particular topic, or any by-mentions by someone discussing the theory etc?

My understanding is that the spacetime warping isn't strong enough that light is completely "bounced" away when it hits the bubble, its direction is just warped - so light from the outside enters from the front and is distorted by the contracted space in front (and the effect would be more pronounced straight ahead (the visualizations I have seen seem to imply the spacetime "pit" is deeper in the front). You would get no light in from the rear since the bubble itself is moving at superluminal speeds.

Hence, from the front everything would look distorted, as if being contracted/pulled in, while the rear would be entirely black. Am I on point or completely missing here? Is the my question even really answerable?

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5708

Answer (score 1):

A conference I attended few years ago had a [talk](https://indico.ict.inaf.it/event/751/contributions/5229/) which answer your questions (see linked slides).

[image]

The main points are (quoting):

- The causal structure of a superluminal warp drive shows the presence
  of black hole and white hole like horizons
- The observer in the bubble
  center will detect a thermal flux at the “Hawking temperature” of the
  black-horizon.
- If quantum inequalities apply the surface gravity, being related to
  the thickness of the bubble walls, will be Planck scale. Hence the
  observer will be suddenly “boiled”!
- At the white horizon there is an exponential accumulation of energy density that will rapidly destabilise the warp.
- At the Cauchy horizon there is also a divergence of the energy density if the warp last forever (but still a very rapid growing energy density even in a short time).

In general the exact behaviour is far from being settled, since different assumptions such as which energy inequalities are satisfied will give different answers, often stretching the limits of what we can do without a full quantum gravity theory.